# ConfigParser instance has no attribute '__setitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, configuration

i'm trying to initialize the config file

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config['Testing'] = {"name": "Yohannes", "age": 10}
with open("test.ini", "w") as configFile: 
    config.write(configFile)
```

but it keeps throwing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\ObjectDetection\src\confWriter.py", line 9, in <module>
    config['Testing'] = {"name": "Yohannes", "age": 10}
AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute '__setitem__'
```

I searched everywhere but didn't find anything

Answer (score 3):

The answer by teivaz is correct, but maybe incomplete. The way you are using the ConfigParser object is almost correct in Python 3 ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)), but not Python 2 ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)).

Here is Python 2:

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section('Testing')
config.set('Testing', 'name', 'Yohannes')
config.set('Testing', 'age', '10')  # note: string value for '10'!
```

And Python 3:

```
import configparser  # note: lowercase module name
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['Testing'] = {'name': 'Yohannes', 'age': '10'}
```

Note: Python 2's `ConfigParser.set()` won't complain if you give it a non-string value (e.g. `config.set('Testing', 'age', 10)`), but it will throw a `TypeError` when you try to retrieve it. Python 3 will throw a `TypeError` when you use the `set()` method with a non-string value, but it will quietly convert values to strings with the `__setitem__` access. E.g.:

```
config['Testing'] = {'name': 'Yohannes', 'age': 10}  # int value for 'age'
config['Testing']['age']  # returns '10' as a string, not an int
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not using it right. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) you can find examples.

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section('Testing')
config.set('Testing', 'name', 'Yohannes')
config.set('Testing', 'age', 10)
```

About the error you are getting you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.%5F%5Fsetitem%5F%5F):

> `object.__setitem__(self, key, value)`
>   Called to implement assignment to `self[key]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
config.Testing = {"name": "Yohannes", "age": 10}
```

Comment: This will not add anything to config